# Android View - Alternatives to finalized() and onDetachFromWindow() for knowing when to terminate threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout

I am extending a View - specifically an ImageView - and performing several flavors of multi-threaded code for various operations that update the view.  These operations will be long running, likely performed via a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

I'd like this view to be available for display in any layout, anywhere in my app - including display via BaseAdapter implementations.  Ideally this view will be fully responsible for terminating threads when it is no longer needed.

Anyone have recommendations for where/how to terminate these threads?  onDetachFromWindow() seems questionable to utilize if the view is being displayed via an adapter.  finalize() is the safest bet but is likely the most expensive place in terms of execution time.

It seems reasonable that, if I want the view to be utilized in a list/gridview, I'll need to provide a public method to "reset" the view to stop threads and start new ones as new data is encountered that drives the view... maybe I should just ditch the idea of using this view within an adapter...

Comment: Generally adapters controls all of the logic for loading the views as the List/GridView will attempt to reuse instances as you scroll. Do you have a particular reason you are making the views complex?

Comment: That is correct, which is the problem at hand - as they get re-used I need to be careful not to have unnecessary operations starting and stopping.  As for complexity, the rendering of the view is not complex.  Just the logic taking place on non-UI threads.